# Java REST service, get List<String> instead of List<Object>

Tags: java, string, list, rest, object

I got a problem when receiving data with REST service.
I am receiving by RequestBody an entity A that contains many properties. One of them is a Set of entity B.

Let's say :

```
Class A { 
Set<B> setOfB;
...
}

Class B {
Integer id;
String lastName;
}
```

If I receive a json like this :

```
{"setOfB": [{"id":1, "lastName":"lastName1"},{"id":2, "lastName":"lastName2"}]}
```

it will work. By the way, if I take off the id or give 2 objects with the same id, it will give the same result as the problem I describe below.

For some reason, I have to receive only a string list:

```
{"setOfB": ["lastName1", "lastName1"]}
```

In this case, my entity will only have a set with the first value (as a B entity).

Do you know how I could manage this : getting the string list and telling Java that each string is the lastName property of an Object A ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your JSON and change it to like below.

{"setOfB": [{"lastName":"lastName1"},{"lastName":"lastName2"}]}

It's gonna work. But if you are sending {"setOfB": ["lastName1", "lastName1"]} java will treat it as List of String. And it will not ab able to parse the JSON to object.

Comment: It gives the same result. It only works if I add the id attribute with each having a different one (giving 0 to each won't work).
I could give a random one that I increment but I'd like to avoid this if possible...
Do you think the property being the primary key HAS TO be indicated no matter what...? Isn't there another way...?

Comment: @Pushi - Why "setOfB" is a Set, can you make it List ?. And if it means to be Set than on what basis you are checking the uniqueness of the object. DId you override the equals() method?